# Symfony2 optional route parameters with keys

Tags: php, symfony, routes

In symfony2 routing.yml I am trying to create a route with optional parameters like this:

```
/app/type/{typeValue}/page/{page}
```

So, an example that would work is:

```
/app/test/type/hello/page/1
```

My route is:

```
api_test:
    pattern:   /api/test/type/{typeValue}/page/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: TestCoreBundle:Json:test, page:1 }
```

This is fine but i want to have /type/{typeValue} and /page/{page} optional so it works also for urls like this:

```
/app/test
/app/test/page/3
/app/test/type/myType
```

My other routes will also contain more complicated optional parameters so it is important for me to solve this problem. What do I need to do so that I dont need to create separate routes so it supports every single combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained on the [symfony page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders) everything after an optional placeholder has to be optional too.

> Of course, you can have more than one optional placeholder (e.g.
>   `/blog/{slug}/{page}`), but everything after an optional placeholder
>   must be optional. For example, `/{page}/blog` is a valid path, but page
>   will always be required (i.e. simply `/blog` will not match this route).

In your case `{typeValue}` is optional but followed by `/page/` which is not optional, so this rout will never work with both parameters optional. 
You can either use query strings or change your route to something like

```
api_test:
    pattern:   /api/test/{typeValue}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: TestCoreBundle:Json:test, typeValue: 'default', page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
```

You will then be able to use routes

```
/app/test
/app/test/myType
/app/test/myType/3
```

But even then route `/app/test/3` is not possible, since symfony will interpret this as `$typeValue = 3` and `$page` as default.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic routing params still need to be filled or defaulted, I would recommend passing these as options then append to a query string such as ?page=1&myType=blah and use $request->get() in your controller, base class.